# Column push down css issue

Tags: css

I have searched the web, but I cannot find the answer. Hope someone help me 
out.

In my page, the right column is push down under the left column because the 
width problem. Is that any way I don't need to change the width for all 
element? I means let the right column is overlap the div which class is 
wrapper?

There is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>My first styled page</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    color: purple;
}

div.wrapper {
    width: 80%;   
    border-style:solid; 
    border-color:black;
}

 div.one {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px; 
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #0000ff;  
}

div.two {
    width: 1024px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:yellow ;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="one">The left column</div>
        <div class="two">The right column</div>
    </div>
?
</body>
```

there is the screen shot of my page:
 [image]

Comment: It's not clear what do you need. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @vucko, I want the right column stick on the next to "left column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first styled page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                color:purple;
            }
            div.wrapper {
                width:80%;   
                float:left;
                border-style:solid; 
                border-color:black;
            }
            div.one {
                width:45%;
                float:left;
                height:300px; 
                border:1px solid blue; 
            }
            div.two {
                width:45%;
                float:right;
                border:1px solid yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="one">The left column</div>
            <div class="two">The right column</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I used your code and create div.three which is wider than div.tow into the div.two. The div.three can stick on right hand side. I don't understand why the div.three can stick on right hand side even the width of div.three is wider than div.wrapper and div.two. Would you explain to me. thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome Chan. Can you kindly share your code for my ease of understanding? Thanks

Comment: I don't know how I post my code in comments. There is my new `div.three class. div.three {    width: 924px;  border-style:solid;
 border-color:green; ;` There is the div.three in body. ` <div class="two">The right column
   <div class="three">addition column</div>
  </div>`
     
}

Comment: @thouhid It is too long on commenct section, so I separete it tow parts. <br/><html>
<head>
  <title>My first styled page</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    color: purple;
   }
 
 div.wrapper {
    width: 80%;   
 border-style:solid; 
 border-color:black;
}
div.one {
    
 width: 45%;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color: #0000ff; 
}
div.two {
    
 width: 45%;
 height: 250px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:yellow ; 
}
 
div.three {
    width: 924px;  
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:green;      
}
  </style>
</head>

Comment: @thouhid, it is second part. <body>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one">The left column</div>
    <div class="two">The right column
   <div class="three">addition column</div>
  </div>
</div>?
</body>

Comment: Fix your syntax. You can take the help of w3c html validator.

Comment: sorry, I typed your username incorrect. Hope you can review my code and explain to me. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Chan: Its okay, I understand. You have not ended all tags properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing second div style to

```
div.two {
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:yellow ;
  margin-left: 310px;
}
```